Can we justify SGD and Simulated Annealing with SDEs?
A few days ago, I came across an interesting question on MSE that piqued my interest. I also asked about it on MO (link: Gibbs measure as stationary distribution of SDEs) to understand its background.
The MSE question is as follows:

I try to get the stationary distribution $$\pi=e^{-H(x)}dx/Z$$ and
$Z=\int e^{-H(x)}dx$ called Gibbs measure for the following SDE:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ld}
     dX_t=-\nabla H(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dB_t, \, X_0=x, \end{equation} where $H(t)$ is the potential function on $R^n$.
Let $P_t$ be the semi-groups of $X_t$ that is
$P_tf(x)=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$ for $t>0$ and smooth functions $f$.
How to verify this Gibbs measure is the stationary distribution with
respect to the semi-group $P_t$? That means for any smooth functions
$f$
$$ \pi(P_t f)=\pi(f)=\int f d\pi $$

Local Minimas and SGD
Just now, I suddenly realized something quite intriguing. Consider the original deterministic ODE
$$ dX = -\nabla H(X) dt $$
This ODE describes a process of gradually descending along the gradient of the function $ H(x) $. However, it does not necessarily have a single equilibrium state. In fact, we do not know the exact shape of $ H(x) $; it may have numerous local minima throughout the space, each of which serves as a stable fixed point for the equation! Specifically, we cannot guarantee that for every initial value, the trajectory will eventually converge to the global minimum.
The situation is different for the SDE, though. From the description of the original problem, we can see that (under very mild conditions, such as the integrability of $ e^{-\beta H(x)} $) it possesses a unique stationary distribution:
$$ \pi = \frac{e^{-\beta H(x)}}{Z} $$
which is the Gibbs distribution. I believe there is an even stronger conclusion: for any initial probability distribution, as time evolves, it will converge to the Gibbs distribution.
This reminds me of stochastic gradient descent methods in machine learning. In the absence of randomness, classical gradient descent may converge to a local minimum rather than the global one. Introducing a stochastic term can improve this situation.
Vanishing Noise and Simulated Annealing
We can observe that the Gibbs distribution depends solely on the value of $H(x) $. Let's assume $ x_0 $ is the unique minimum point of $ H(x) $; then $ \pi $ achieves its maximum at $ x_0 $. If we allow the coefficient in front of $ B_t $ in the SDE to converge to $0$, gradually reducing the magnitude of the random perturbation, intuitively, it is clear that the value of $ \beta $ in the stationary distribution $ \pi $ will increasingly concentrate around $ x_0 $. I believe that $ \pi $ will eventually converge to a Dirac distribution centered at $ x_0 $.
This truly makes me think of simulated annealing, where the system's temperature decreases over time, and the random perturbations diminish. Additionally, even from a purely mathematical perspective, this phenomenon is fascinating: even a tiny amount of random perturbation can lead to drastic changes in the long-term behavior of the original dynamical system.
My Question
I'm excited about the connection between SDEs and these algorithms. However, I have not seen this SDE mentioned directly in the popular science materials I've read on machine learning. My question is whether practitioners in machine learning utilize this SDE to explain the effectiveness of gradient descent and simulated annealing, among other algorithms. Do they leverage any specific properties of this equation? Are there phenomena that remain unexplained by this equation, necessitating further research? Is there any specialized or popular literature that specifically addresses this?
I must emphasize that this is not a clearly defined question. Moreover, under my previous MO inquiry, this answer already provided some good descriptions and references. However, compared to that MO question, this one focuses more on the specifics of machine learning. The ability to connect rigorous mathematical results with a currently hot application field truly excites me, and I hope that interested individuals can gain insight into this topic.

I would like to point out that while MSE features a lot of pure mathematics, optimization is also a significant area of focus here. Compared to other Stack Exchange communities, discussions about the foundational theories and derivations related to optimization and machine learning are often found in MSE. Therefore, I believe my question is relevant and fits well within the scope of this site.
